# In wso2 esb how to get a single number(integer) value

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 ESB after calling an endpoint I am getting the response as number(ex: 78) with header **application/json**, if without processing the response if i send in out sequence it works fine i'll get the same response. But if I include any mediators for processing in between it'll throw exceptions like **Could not save JSON payload. Invalid input stream found**. A single string or number is not valid in some cases So, it may throwing the exception but this bug is resolved in wso2 EI 6.2.

So now I am able to process the response but if I use script mediator to get that value it shows `{}`. If i use json-eval($.) then also i am not able to get the value, also with xpath i am not able to get.

So how to get that response(the value in number) for further processing in wso2 ei, by using script mediator or by using json path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the response only contains a number with the content-type header with application/json. you can take the value to a property as below.

```
<property name="RESPONSE_NUMBER" expression="//jsonValue" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
```

When you need this value somewhere else in the mediation flow you can take the value from the property(in this case RESPONSE_NUMBER) as below.

```
$ctx:RESPONSE_NUMBER
```

Here is a sample API which demonstrates how you can take the response value and use it in the mediation flow.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SampleAPI" context="/getNumber">
   <resource methods="GET">
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET" uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b02cc2c3000006600cee384"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="RESPONSE_NUMBER" expression="//jsonValue" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"Id": $1}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_NUMBER"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

You can call the API with below curl command:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8280/getNumber
```